# fullCalendar jquery users id

Tags: jquery, mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, fullcalendar

Im trying to implement a Medic Online Date System with a fullCalendar on ruby on rails. (College Project) need help please.

So the real question is this. If i have 2 medics, example Alex and Alfred and Alex User_id = 1 and Alfred User_id = 2. If Alex is logged in my Medic Online System as **User_id 1**, fullCalendar will show only **User_id = 1** appointments and not all of the medics appointments, and viceverse with Alfred, if im logged in with Alfred's account fullCalendar then will show me only Alfred's appointments.

Note: All my database is fully functionally with users_id but i have NO CLUE how to validate this id to show different medics appointments and not all the medic appointments.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you log in store the user_id in a session:

`session[:user_id]=user.id`

in your application controller

```
class ApplicationController < ...
  def current_user
    @current_user ||= session[:user_id] && User.find_by_id(session[:user_id]) # Use find_by_id to get nil instead of an error if user doesn't exist
  end
  helper_method :current_user #make this method available in views
end
```

Now you can user `current_user` in your views or controllers

Use the ID to filter out the events. Check out the CanCanCan gem, or if this is as simple as it gets then do

```
def index
 @events = current_user.events #display these
end
```

Comment: I'm sorry im new to this enviroment so i dont know where to place that method to make it work. This is my index metho
 `def infex
@events = Event.all
end`

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what needs to change. How do you reference your logged in user(it should be current_user)

Comment: That's exactly what i need to do, reference my logged user with current_user_id and place it somewhere in my project so fullCalendar can reconize it and show it the specific appointments. but i dont know how